# MYSQL: Validate Input Values in Specific Format within a FUNCTION

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have one question with regard to MYSQL. I want to create a function that is able to check whether an Input is given in a specific format.

The output should be in the following shape:

```
***x x (a) n (n) (n) (n)
with :
x = letters and numbers
n = numbers
a = letters
brackets = optional Values***
```

my code is written below this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION validate_of_number(testnumber VARCHAR(7))
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN
    CASE
        WHEN
            (SELECT * FROM flightexecution WHERE FlightNo REGEXP 
            '^[[:alnum:]+[:alnum:]] + [[:alpha:]|''] + [:digit:] + 
            [[:digit:]|''] + [[:digit:]|''] + [[:digit:]|'']') > 0
            Then 1
            Else 0
            END;`
```

However, it does not work and i don´t know why. The Output is just a 'OK' without any further information.

Comment: The function never does anything with `testnumber`.

Comment: What do you mean by `OK`? The function returns `1` or `0`, not a string like `OK`.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use `WHEN (SELECT * ...) > 0`. When you use a subquery as an expression, it has to return just one row and one column. Perhaps you meant `WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) > 0`. You can also write that as `WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming based on your description of valid values and the context of your question that the values you are trying to validate look something like `CX727` or `QF1566` or `BA1` etc (i.e. IATA flight designator codes). In that case, this function will give you the results you want:

```
CREATE FUNCTION validate_of_number(testnumber VARCHAR(7))
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN testnumber REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]{2}[[:alpha:]]?[[:digit:]]{1,4}$';
```

Examples:

```
SELECT validate_of_number('A1B4352')
     , validate_of_number('QF12')
     , validate_of_number('CX727')
     , validate_of_number('AB14352')
     , validate_of_number('BA1')
     , validate_of_number('1C42')
```

Output

```
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21a7a9095ebb0c73e47b580f86864152)

In terms of using it with your table you might use a query like

```
SELECT * FROM flightexecution WHERE validate_of_number(FlightNo)
```

Comment: Hello Nick. Thank you very much. It seems to work. However, i have a question cause i need to understand it. Why do you use double brackets like '[[:alpha:]]' ? What is the sense behind this? Do you have a link to a website where i can read about this informatinos?

Comment: @Jimbo.Koen the `[:alpha:]` is a POSIX character class (google that and you will find lots of info e.g. [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)) that is equivalent to `A-Za-z`. To put it into a set of characters to match, you have to enclose it in `[` and `]` (just as you would write `[A-Za-z]`. Likewise `[[:alnum:]]` is equivalent to `[[:alpha:][:digit:]]` which is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9]`